# How to call the methods in a dll from javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, dll

I created a c# class library. I need to to call a method in the library file  javascript using the dll.The javascript will be embedded in a web page already created. The dll will be on the client machine. Can someone help?
Ps:the method returns a boolean

More details: Actually the website is a virtual web conferencing software in which each one has a particualr avatar. I have to detect whether a particular software(needed for making video calls) is installed in the user's system.If it is installed i have to indicate that by showing some special symbols on his avatar.I made a c# class library which returns "true" if the software is installed in the system.Now i have to embed this in the virtual conferencing web software

I am new to c# and javascript programming!

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Will this web page just be browsed to or is it hosted in some way like through a WebBrowser control?

Comment: Is the DLL COM Visible? Does the web browser have weak security? You should keep the DLL server side and call it with AJAX perhaps.

Comment: Such behavior is not fit for public websites.

Comment: "I am new to c# and javascript programming!" + Invoking DLLs on user-system from websites = security disaster ready to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ActiveXObject class: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/38890-activex-with-c%23/

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

You need to register your dll at the destination computer. 
Than in js you need to create ActiveX object with the same registered name

```
var ObjFromDll = new ActiveXObject("DllRegisteredName");
```

and call it's method.

```
var anyResult = ObjFromDll.MyMethod()
```